# How to find the root cause of HTTP Request Node - Intermittently throwing SocketException: Connection reset?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

HTTP Request node connecting to a third party REST API, which is hosted on AWS intermittently throwing SocketException : Connection reset. I would like to know why is it happening intermittently and how to find root cause of this issue.

HTTP Request Node Settings:
Protocol - TLSv1.2

IBM Integration Bus v10.0.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but there are few things that you can check

1.try your rest API URL on the browser, see if you can get your data if you can see your data so it's not your API problem

2. In `HTTP requests node`,  in basic property, you should write `/`, for example,`/getdata`, not `getdata`

3.in `HTTP` setting property, use the correct method, if you are getting, use get

4.if all set, you can just pass data to `HTTP replay` or you can use `compute node` to modify data however you like then pass to `HTTP replay`.

I hope these work for you

Answer (score 0):

There might be too many solution to answer correctly to your question.

In my experience, the main reasons are the following :

1. Your call took longer than the remote server can accept.
2. You have network issues
3. The Rest API you try to contact is not stable enough (e.g : accept a maximum amount of connection and sometime it is reached, the remote server restarts, ...)

The best way to investigate on this is to try to find something in common with all the call that fails. But anyway, this issue is most likely not on your side since this error means the remote server closed the connection. (Edit : this might also come from a proxy in between, a load balancer, ...)

If you work with a partner and have a contract or contact, you should definitly ask them to check, it's the easiest way